# Android Recurring Insert SQL Statement

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to do recurring insert SQL statement in Android. Here is the code where I populate my listview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recur_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_ddate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayRecurDate);

            viewHolder.txt_damount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayRecurAmount);

            viewHolder.txt_dfrequency = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayFrequency);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Format and calculate the next payment date based on frequency
        try {
            String dateStr = _recurlist.get(position)
                    .getRecurringStartDate();
            String frequencyStr = _recurlist.get(position).getFrequency();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateStr));

            if (frequencyStr.equals("Daily")) {
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText("Next Payment On: "
                        + dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            } else if (frequencyStr.equals("Weekly")) {
                cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
                viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText("Next Payment On: "
                        + dateFormat.format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
                cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
            } 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dfrequency.setText(_recurlist.get(position)
                .getFrequency().trim());

        // Formatting amount into currency format
        float amount = _recurlist.get(position).getRecurringAmount();

        if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("W")) {
            viewHolder.txt_damount.setTextColor(Color.rgb(180, 4, 4));
            viewHolder.txt_damount.setText("Debit $ " + amount);
        } else if (_recurlist.get(position).getRecurringType().equals("D")) {
            viewHolder.txt_damount.setTextColor(Color.rgb(8, 138, 8));
            viewHolder.txt_damount.setText("Credit $ " + amount);
        }

        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            if (date.equals(
                    viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText())) {
            if(currentDate.equals(viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText())){
                DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(Recurring.this);
                mDbHelper.createDatabase();
                mDbHelper.open();
                TransactionRecModel trm = new TransactionRecModel();

                trm.setDate(txtRecurDate.getText().toString());
                trm.setTransDescription(txtRecurDesc.getText().toString());
                if (radioWithdraw.isChecked()) {
                    trm.setType("W");
                } else if (radioDeposit.isChecked()) {
                    trm.setType("D");
                }
                trm.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(txtRecurAmount.getText().toString()));
                trm.setCategory(categoryID);

                TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
                        mDbHelper.open());
                if (trc.addTransactionRec(trm)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Recurring.this,
                            "Transaction Record Added successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mDbHelper.close();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Recurring.this,
                            "Error occured, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        return convertView;
    }
```

I have retrieved the date from database then perform some function to get the next payment date based on the frequency. So what I am trying to do is when the next payment date is today, it should automatically execute the insert SQL statement. However, from my code, it does not execute the insert SQL nor showing error.

I wonder why is it so. And I also wonder do I need a timer for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You´re comparing a date to a text value, this will be false `currentDate.equals(viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText())` you must convert both values to same notation or type.

You may compare the `mDay + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mYear` with the `viewHolder.txt_ddate.getText()`.

And yes, you should take a look to https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html because your user MUST see the screen for this to happen otherwise.

Comment: Nope, doesnt work still even after I changed the variable type of currentDate to string. But my one no need alarm or notification, just that when the date match, it will insert the record

Comment: Have u converted both to String? could u inspect both String values and see if format fits?

Comment: Let me run in debug mode to check for a while

Comment: I managed to get the same date format already but it does not execute the insert SQL statement still. Do you have any idea?

Comment: no brackets missing? I´ve copied the code to eclipse and it seems not to be equilibrated. Does the code run up to the addTransactionRec? is there any error in the log? no null/invalid values passed to the insert?